# ngf-accept works only in input, not in divs

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I've code where `ngf-accept` works properly only when I use input. What could be the reason? In jsfiddle it looks ok with divs.

```
<div class="img-circle center-block" name="file" ngf-select="upload($files)" ngf-
accept="image/*" accept="image/*">
 <img ng-src="{{avatar.avatar(this)}}">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1f36wg8/

In jsfiddle div is working fine with filtering. In my code, only input works correclty.

Comment: Where is your `Jsfiddle` ?

Comment: use ngf-accept instead of accept.